# Python SQL Alchemy connection to MSSQL Error

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm using below pypyodbc library in python to connect with our SQL Server Database and it works perfectly.

```
import pypyodbc as odbc
conn = odbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
Server};SERVER=serverv1;DATABASE=CMS;UID=Test;PWD=Test')
```

Now I want to use SQL Alchemy library to upload my excel data to our SQL Server database, however when I apply the same connection properties, I got an error.

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    #dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database --> Syntax
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Test:Test@serverv1/CMS')
    cwd = os.getcwd()

    XLFile = (cwd +'/FILES/MARCH.xlsx')
    xl = pd.read_excel(XLFile,sheet_name='SALES')

    xl.to_sql('WES', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

    print(xl)
```

I used the same log in info but unsuccessful in SQL Alchemy. I already tried some of the samples here but no luck. Please help need to establish my connection.

Error encountered.

```
    File 
"C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 597, in connect
            return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
        sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
        (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works using pymssql, instead of pyodbc.

Install pymssql using pip, then change your code to:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pymssql://username:password@servername/dbname")
```

if it doesn't work downgrade your sqlalchemy

Comment: thanks for the inputs, may I ask how to downgrade to lower version ?

Comment: pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.35 if  1.4.36 exists first uninstall it then install specific version @Trunks

Comment: Done downgrading but still not works.
`C:\Users\test>pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.35
Collecting SQLAlchemy==1.4.35
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.4.35-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)`

Error 
`Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist `

Comment: its your MSSQL error, your py codes are ok now